# Update application on rooted device and start it manually

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, root

I'm writing an application in `kotlin` and `java` and on only rooted `TV-Box`es. I've added a feature to download apk file from my own server and install it and after installation rerun it:

```
                        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: writeByte install");
                        cs.writeBytes(String.format("cat %s | pm install -S %d\n", strings[0], length));
                        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: writeByte start activity");
                        cs.writeBytes(("am start -n com.exam.ple.views/com.exam.ple.views.SplashActivity" +
                                " --ez update true\n"));
```

The problem is that this code works fine if the signed apk file is in debug mode. But when it is in release mode, it doesn't work properly, meaning that the application installs successfully but doesn't start the activity (and just when it is signed as release APK).
I've checked the `am start ...` in terminal(`Termux`) and it works fine under all circumstances.

Any idea what could cause this problem?

Comment: Do you use the same signature for debug and release APKs? If you install an app, you can also install updates to it signed with the exact same private key/certificate.

Comment: The signature of debug and release APKs are different, but I don't suppose that matters, since we try to update debug version using debug APKs and release versions using release APKs.

Comment: It is possible that proguard changes the name `com.exam.ple.views/com.exam.ple.views.SplashActivity`. you could try with something like `SplashActivity.class.getCanonicalName()` instead of `com.exam.ple.views.SplashActivity`.

Comment: How can we make sure whether this happens or not?

Comment: You can configure proguard behaviour (`proguard-rules.pro`) , yes

Comment: If proguard did change the name, then would Termux be able to open the activity?

Comment: I don't know, it was just an idea. Can you show the errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239942/discussion-between-ali73-and-dan1st).